# How to use Users service of google app engine with the bottle.py framework?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to use the users service of GAE to integrate with Google Account.This is my code.

```
from framework import bottle
from framework.bottle import route, template, request, error, debug
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app 
from google.appengine.api import users



@route('/')
def DisplayForm():
    if user:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This code throws an error:

```
File "/home/saikat/Desktop/GOOG_PROJ/bgae/main.py", line 20, in DisplayForm
    self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Adding self as a parameter in DisplayForm() does not help either.Any ideas on how to proceed? 
I am using python 2.7. Development environment is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import response and redirect from bottle and remove `self` in DisplayForm.

```
from framework.bottle import route, template, request, error, debug, response, redirect
```

In DisplayForm:

```
if user:
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    response.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
else:
    redirect(users.create_login_url(request.url))
```

Comment: I did as you asked.But I get a new exception

`AttributeError("Attribute 'uri' not defined.",)`

Comment: That's why I think it's better to `from framework import bottle` and then `bottle.response`, `bottle.redirect..`, etc

Comment: Ya did that too.Current snapshot of my code:

`@route('/')`  
`def DisplayForm():`
    `user = users.get_current_user()`
    `if user:`
        `response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'`
        `response.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())`
    `else:`
        `redirect(users.create_login_url(request.uri))`

Also did all the imports as you suggested.(response,redirect)

Comment: It is `request.url` and not `request.uri`.

Comment: Actually 'uri' appears as an apparent typo in Google's own channel api tutorial. I had the same problem.